# Wrong Signature.ACCEPTS after .wrap sub

Tags: raku

After I wrap a sub the signature do not ACCEPTS a Capture accepted before wrapping.

```
sub wr(:$a) {say $a};
my $sig-before = &wr.signature;
say $sig-before;               # (:$a)
say %(:a(3)) ~~ $sig-before;   # True

&wr.wrap(-> |c {callsame(c)});
my $sig-after = &wr.signature;
say $sig-after;                # (:$a)
say %(:a(3)) ~~ $sig-after;    # False
say %(:a(3)) ~~ $sig-before;   # False

say $sig-before.WHICH, ' ', $sig-after.WHICH; # Signature|140466574255752 Signature|140466574255752
say $sig-before eq $sig-after; # True
say %(:a(3)).Capture ~~ $sig-after; # 'Cannot invoke object with invocation handler in this context'
say $sig-after.ACCEPTS(%(:a(3)).Capture); # 'Cannot invoke object with invocation handler in this context'
```

I see in Rakudo code:

```
multi method ACCEPTS(Signature:D: Capture $topic) {
    nqp::p6bool(nqp::p6isbindable(self, nqp::decont($topic)));
}
```

Probably it is a bug? Or how can I workaround that behavior if it is expected and how can I understand in run time that I have do the workaround in concrete case?

Answer (score 6):

**2022 update** Works as @MikhailKhorkov expected in a recent Rakudo (v2022.02):

```
(:$a)
True
(:$a)
True
True
Signature|4343308333200 Signature|4343308333200
True
True
True
```

## Original answer

> Probably it is a bug?

I've been wrong before when I call something a bug but I'd say *something* in there is a bug, even if it's just a Less Than Awesome error message bug.

I think `wrap` has relatively few [roast tests](https://github.com/perl6/roast/search?q=wrap&unscoped_q=wrap) (many matches are false positives; search for `wrap(` or `wrap:` in the results). One key thing to do here if you want to use wrap is add a roast test covering what we want it to do here that it is not doing correctly (assuming it's not just a Less Than Awesome error message).

I think wrap is one of the most fragile official P6 features:

- [new/open/stalled bugs in RT Perl 6 queue matching 'wrap'](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Search/Results.html?Query=Queue%20=%20%27perl6%27%20AND%20(Status%20=%20%27new%27%20OR%20Status%20=%20%27open%27%20OR%20Status%20=%20%27stalled%27)%20AND%20Subject%20like%20%27wrap%27).
- [new/open/stalled bugs in RT Perl 6 queue matching 'Cannot invoke object with invocation handler in this context'](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Search/Results.html?Query=Queue%20=%20%27perl6%27%20AND%20(Status%20=%20%27new%27%20OR%20Status%20=%20%27open%27%20OR%20Status%20=%20%27stalled%27)%20AND%20Subject%20like%20%27Cannot%20invoke%20object%20with%20invocation%20handler%20in%20this%20context%27).
- [open rakudo repo issues matching 'wrap'](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+wrap).
- [open rakudo repo issues matching 'Cannot invoke object with invocation handler in this context'](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+%27Cannot+invoke+object+with+invocation+handler+in+this+context%27).